# Role Based Object-Oriented Design - Controller

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I'd like to implement a system that actually encompasses 3, each one varying in functionality by user role type. I.e. a system that allows users to perform different tasks based on their role type; role type determined right at user creation. The users cannot use their role to access other components / features of the system, and the UI is unique for each user.*

I need these "systems" to act independently of each other, but I'm finding some common behavior (most often, opportunities for composition) across the board.

Currently, I have 3 controllers, as this was the original intent of my design - RoleType1Controller, RoleType2Controller, RoleType3Controller. Obviously, these branch out independently, and touch the classes they need to touch.

I'm preparing for some pretty large enhancements in functionality as soon as I get my feet off the ground and need to take these enhancements into consideration, as some of them will be co-driving points of the system. I.e. I want the system to do a couple things, all of equal importance, but can only implement one major feature at this time.

Concerning the OOD, I'm thinking this "three systems in one" approach may be best suited for upcoming changes. However, these opportunities for composition and the desire to keep with standards of having a single controller is weighing heavily on my decision making process.

Does anyone have experience with something like this or, if not, is experienced in OOD and can point me in the right direction? I'm building from the ground up, so (obviously) the framework of the system is being defined in this first iteration. I'd like it to be as robust and flexible as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I am NOT using the UI to drive my design process...I just thought this extra bit of information may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, in this case, is to have multiple controllers. Not necessarily by role (though this is how my domain model is currently formed); these should be defined through the process of delegating use case controllers responsibility. I found this through my initial stage of design - defining SSDs and the class diagram.

In *Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development* (an incredible introductory book pulling its context from various, proven best practice definitions and their authors), Craig Larman states there are two ways to approach defining your controllers:

> Assign the responsibility to a class representing one of the following choices:
>
> • Represents the overall “system,” a “root object,” a device that the software is running within, or a major
>   subsystem—these are all variations of a facade controller.
>
> • Represents a use case scenario within which the system event occurs, often named Handler,
>   Coordinator, or Session (use case or session controller).
>
> > • Use the same controller class for all system events in the same use case scenario.
> >
> > • Informally, a session is an instance of a conversation with an actor. Sessions can be of any length but are
> >     often organized in terms of use cases (use case sessions).

Previous experience has always lead me to the first solution, because the systems I was helping design were of a much lower level of complexity. However, I ran into this issue: **bloated controller**.

From the same text, Larman proposes this:

> **Issues and Solutions**
>
> Poorly designed, a controller class will have low cohesion—unfocused and handling too many areas of responsibility;
>   this is called a bloated controller. Signs of bloating are:
>
> • There is only a single controller class receiving all system events in the system, and there are many of them.
>   This sometimes happens if a facade controller is chosen.
>
> • The controller itself performs many of the tasks necessary to fulfill the system event, without delegating the
>   work. This usually involves a violation of Information Expert and High Cohesion.
>
> • A controller has many attributes, and it maintains significant information about the system or domain, which should have been distributed to other objects, or it duplicates information found elsewhere.
>   Among the cures for a bloated controller are these two:
>
> > 1. Add more controllers—a system does not have to need only one. Instead of facade controllers, employ use case controllers. 
> >        For example, consider an application with many system events, such as an airline reservation system. It may contain the following controllers:
> >
> > > > Use case controllers
> > > >
> > > > > MakeReservationHandler
> > > >
> > > > Use case controllers
> > > >
> > > > > ManageSchedulesHandler
> > > > >
> > > > > ManageFaresHandler
> >
> > 2. Design the controller so that it primarily delegates the fulfillment of each system operation responsibility
> >        to other objects.

2) by itself wasn't going to help me because I had actors speaking to the same classes but in their own ways...I was already delegating as much responsibility as I could to other classes while trying to maintain a simple and consistent interaction for the user. As stated before, this lead me to the "bloated controller" issue.

Because OOA/D is an evolving process, I won't be able to say this is my final solution until it's truly implemented. Really, these use case controllers could lead me down a different path...instead of (like) controllers for each (like) use case, I could end up with 3 (or 4 or 5 or 6), and this may be just a means of getting there. But for now, things are going a lot smoother than they were before - I'm beginning to see the realization of the ultimate solution.